# Mysql Database data maintenance

Tags: mysql, database

I have two tables.
City and Survey.

```
City
id int(11) primary key,
Name varchar(255)

Survey
Id int(11) primary key,
CityId ref City.id,
```

Other columns...

For example,
London is in City table and id is 23.
I have surveys in survey table with cityId 23.

When I delete London from city table, I don't want to delete rows from survey table.
I also need to report survey details with city name. But, London is deleted I'm city table.

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: Basically, you don't want London to be deleted if `Survey` is referring to it.

Answer (score 0):

You "solve" this problem by creating a foreign key reference in `Survey`:

```
alter table survey add constraint fk_survey_cityid
    foreign key (cityid) references city(id);
```

Then, when you attempt to delete London from the `city` table, the delete will fail.  Another table references the id.

Comment: What I meant is I need to delete London from the city table. But, I don't want to end up with just integer id in cityId column from survey table.

Comment: @KaungSiTher . . . You don't seem to understand how databases work.  You can add a deletion flag to the cities table.

Answer (score 0):

**If you don't want to delete rows from survey table**

For example, adds a default city

Example: City NC with id 0

In your poll, you set a default value to the column CityId value 0;

```
UPDATE Survey  SET CityId=0 WHERE CityId = CityneedDelete ;
```

And

```
DELETE FROM City where CityId = CityneedDelete
```

Comment: I came up with another solution. I created another table named deletedCity. Deleted city from city table would be added to this created table.